# Javascript - No aplica style al utilizar name="" como referencia

Tags: javascript

No aplica style al utilizar name="area" como referencia de las etiquetas:
¿Qué sucede?

Javascript:

```
<script>
  var area = document.getElementsByName("area").innerHTML;
  if (area == "Superior") {
    document.getElementsByName("area").style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
  }
  if (area == "Inferior") {
    document.getElementsByName("area").style.backgroundColor = "#0000ff";
  }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<p name="area">Superior</p>
<p name="area">Inferior</p>
<p name="area">Inferior</p>
<p name="area">Superior</p>
```

Comment: El método getElement**s**ByName devuelve una colección de elementos, tendrás que iterar por ellos para aplicar el estilo.

Comment: ¿Con class sucede lo mismo?

Comment: ¿Probablemente hay mejores alternativas para esto?

Comment: Julián, sucede lo mismo con todos los métodos para obtener elementos que su nombre comienza con `getElements`, en plural. Son arrays y nadie tiene problema con ellos, exceptuando los que no lo saben aún. Otras opciones pueden ser usar jQuery

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que deseas es que se indpendiente a su posicion, deberas hacer un for  que recorra todos los elementos con `name="area"`

```js
var areas = document.getElementsByName("area");
areas.forEach((area) => {
  if (area.innerText == "Superior") {
    area.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
  } else if (area.innerText == "Inferior") {
    area.style.backgroundColor = "#0000ff";
  }
})
```

```html
<p name="area">Superior</p>
<p name="area">Inferior</p>
<p name="area">Inferior</p>
<p name="area">Superior</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Como bien ya te mencionaron al tener un conjunto de valores devueltos, deberías:

- Iterar sobre ellos
- Elegir los deseados por medio del índice que ocupa el valor deseado

Puedes por ejemplo a través de `getElementsByName` recuperar los elementos que tengan un name con el valor de area, posterior verificar si los elementos en los índices 0 y 1 cumplen con una condición y en caso afirmativo darle un valor

> Lo anterior lo lograrás colocando el índice entre corchetes

```
<p name="area">Superior</p>
<p name="area">Inferior</p>
<p name="area">Inferior</p>
<p name="area">Superior</p>

<script>
  var area = document.getElementsByName("area");
  if (area[0].innerText == "Superior") {
    document.getElementsByName("area")[0].style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
  }
  if (area[1].innerText == "Inferior") {
    document.getElementsByName("area")[1].style.backgroundColor = "#0000ff";
  }
</script>
```